# Backup Quora answers

Tags: applications

How can I backup custom content contributed to Quora with the Quora app so that I can keep a local copy of my answers to questions found therein? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Quora app, and the only feature I'm aware of is taking screenshots to save your answers. I haven't found anything in the app that will save a local copy of answers. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Well Quora app doesn't have that feature as of now, but another app can help you doing it.

[Copy Bubble APP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.copybubble&hl=en) This app is a clipboard history app, it maintains history of your copied content,  which you can export to pdf, mail of txt file.